# Views exposed filter returns all results when using Autosubmit

Tags: views

This is slightly different than other people asking questions about an exposed filter returning results before they found the 'Input Required' option. Here is the scenario:

I have a series of 'county' nodes that are very simple - the title is the Zip Code, and there is an additional 'county' field that is the county. So for example the title is '78872' and the county field is 'Zavala'. I have then set up a View that allows a user to enter in a zip code in an exposed filter field and the corresponding county will be displayed. Since there is only one county that corresponds to a zip code, only 1 result should be returned (counties have multiple zip codes, but zip codes only correspond to 1 county).

The client wanted the form to autosubmit when the user input a zip code, so I have the following settings for the exposed form:

[image: views autosubmit]

When the user first comes to the page, before they enter anything in the exposed form field, I also have it set to 'Input required' so nothing is displayed until the user enters in a zip code:

[image: input required]

You can see it here https://texaslawhelp.org/legal-help/legal-help-finder

If there are no matches when you enter a zip code, it simply says 'no results found'. I did this by configuring the view under Advanced->No results behavior.

[image: no results behavior]

Here is the issue, once someone starts entering zip codes, if they then delete everything from the exposed filter form, it still shows a result. To duplicate this, enter in a zip code (78872) - Zavala is returned.

[image: enter zip code]

[image: county returned]

Then without refreshing the page, delete 78872 from the exposed filter and it returns 'El Paso'.

[image: el paso]

I believe this is because if nothing is entered in the exposed filter, it will match everything, and is just returning all results in a random order. Since the user has already input something, the 'Input Required' option no longer is in the mix. Only 1 result is displayed since I have the view set up to only display 1 result - there should only ever be 1 county returned when a zip code is entered. If I change the view to display 200 results (even though only 1 should ever match) I can see that if I enter something in the field, and then delete it, 200 results are found. So it seems pretty clear that it is a problem where every possible node is a match if nothing is entered in the field.

So, is there a workaround? Views and the exposed filter are actually working correctly as far as I can tell, so what is the trick for hiding any results if that exposed filter field is empty after the user has input something and then deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Maybe "El Paso" has a relation with a "Null Zip code"

**2.** You can go to "Configure Field -> No results behavior and select "Hide if empty"

Maybe that can fix your problem

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this but nope those aren't correct. For your point 1: If I change it to return 200 results (instead of 1) if I go through the same steps ie enter a zip code, then delete it from the exposed filter field (without refreshing the page) I get 200 results, not just El Paso, but lots of other zip code nodes. So it seems pretty clear that it is returning ALL results, since anything matches. I've updated my post to address your comment #2.